# I dont know why my batch if and goto isnt working

Tags: if-statement, batch-file, goto

I dont know why my batch if and goto isnt working
it works until the user has to pick a choice to run.  The whole thing just shutsdown
Here is my script:

```
@Echo off
:Password  
set input=
set b=
set c=
set /p input=Password:
if %input%==******** goto yes
if not %input%==******** goto no
cls
:yes
cls
echo Access Accepted! Welcome Tucker!
echo.
set /p op=Enter Your Full-Name For Access:
if %op%== TuckerGarySiegel goto home
cls
:no
echo Wrong Password. Access Denied. No Entry.
goto password
cls
:home
color 1f
```

This is what I think is the problem area

```
Echo Welcome Tucker!
echo 1) My Batch Files
echo 2) Google Chrome
set /p input=Type Your Selection: 
if %c%== 1 goto batch

if not %c%== 1 goto home


pause
cls
:batch
echo Choose File:
echo 1) Password Script

set /p b=Make Selection: 
if %b%== 1 goto passscript
pause
cls
:passscript
```

i still need to make the rest

please help

Comment: First password, *then* name... Unusual, but interesting.

Answer (score 4):

```
set /p input=Type Your Selection: 
if %c%== 1 goto batch
if not %c%== 1 goto home
```

You're setting the variable `input` but then checking the variable `c`.  Try this instead, which will allow it to work:

```
set /p input=Type Your Selection: 
if %input%== 1 goto batch
if not %input%== 1 goto home
```

---

P.S. you don't need to check an `if` and an `if not`.  Doing this would be just fine:

```
set /p input=Type Your Selection: 
if %input%== 1 goto batch
goto home
```